# Google Natural Language API - English Gerund

Tags: google-sheets, google-natural-language

Im using Google's NLP Api to analyze sentences and retrieve part of speech tokens form cells in a google drive sheet using appScript.

The problem is I can't retrieve or identify any of the words in the sentence as gerunds.
From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/Token#form) GERUND is token of Form.

For example, in this sentence "She enjoys dancing and singing"
"dancing" and "singing" are both gerunds, but all the words return FORM_UNKNOWN

AppScript .gs code

```
    function analyzeTest(){
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const ws = ss.getSheetByName(“My Sheet“);
      var commentEnCellVal = ws.getRange('C24').getValue();
          console.log("C24 value " + commentEnCellVal);//the value in cell C24 is “She enjoys dancing and singing”
          var aTag = [];
          var aForm = [];
          var aTense = [];
          //…
      if (commentEnCellVal) {
        var nlData = retrieveEntitySentiment(commentEnCellVal);  
        var newValues = []
        for (var token of nlData.tokens) {
          var row = [token.partOfSpeech.tag, 
                     token.partOfSpeech.form,
                     token.partOfSpeech.tense];
          //I’m retrieveing all available tags, tense, moon, aspect…etc including dependecy tags 
          //and pushing into the arrays
          aTag.push(token.partOfSpeech.tag);
          aForm.push(token.partOfSpeech.form);
          aTense.push(token.partOfSpeech.tense);
        }
                 
      }
      var tags = aTag;
      var form = aForm;
      var tense = aTense;
      console.log("tags " + tags);
      console.log("form " + form);
      console.log("tense "+ tense);     
}
```

The console log

```
C24 value She enjoys dancing and singing.
tags PRON,VERB,VERB,CONJ,NOUN,PUNCT
form FORM_UNKNOWN,FORM_UNKNOWN,FORM_UNKNOWN,FORM_UNKNOWN,FORM_UNKNOWN,FORM_UNKNOWN
tense TENSE_UNKNOWN,PAST,TENSE_UNKNOWN,TENSE_UNKNOWN,TENSE_UNKNOWN,TENSE_UNKNOWN
```

This the NLP function (I've also tried language.googleapis.com/v1, same result)

```
function retrieveEntitySentiment(line) {
      var apiKey = “****”;
      var apiEndpoint = 'https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta2/documents:analyzeSyntax?key=' + apiKey; 
      // Create json request, w/ text, language, type & encoding
      var nlData = {
        document: {
          language: 'en-us',
          type: 'PLAIN_TEXT',
          content: line
        },
        encodingType: 'UTF8'
        //apiVersion: '2.9.0'
      };
      //  Package all of the options and the data together for the call
      var nlOptions = {
        method: 'post',
        modelType:'latest',
        modelVersion:'latest',
        apiVersion: '2.9.0',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        payload: JSON.stringify(nlData)
        
      };
      //  And make the call
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiEndpoint, nlOptions);
      return JSON.parse(response);
    };
```

I guess I can set some sort of rule/conditions checking diff tags to know if it's a Gerund, but I'd like to know if there is something wrong in the code which Im not seeing. Thanks.